# Refreshing page with runtime error

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, iis-6, runtime-error

I wonder if refreshing page with runtime error will overload the web server. For example I did refreshed domain.com/default.asp?id=99999999999999999999999999999999999999999 page which generates following error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a000d'

Type mismatch: 'Cint'

/default.asp, line 9
```

This caused server not respond for all sites hosted on it **or** my IP was blocked for some time by the firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what the rest of the code around that error looks like (which you can't see). You won't overload the server in the sense of DoS too many requests (flood) since those would be handled before the request gets to IIS to process on the server side.

But if the code where the page breaks does other processing based on that value it could crash IIS or the app pool. It could also be stuck waiting on a passed DB call and has to timeout before the server responds. It will either time out or reset itself and that is when you see the site functional again.

Either way the code or the website/server should be setup better to alleviate the problem. Hopefully the admins will figure that out when they investigate why the site keeps crashing due to your web hits ;)

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be type casting. Try below steps.

Add this line on top of the page where you get this error:

```
"Option Explicit"
```

You can get more meaning ful error message:

This [link](http://classicasp.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-i-get-errors-in-the-800a0001-800a000f-range.html) provide details for each error message.

Comment: I am not worried about fixing it because it is not a page of mine.